# Trying to create a (list or array, not sure) with data I have outputted from a nested for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, printing, enumerate

My nested for loop above end with

```
print print1,
print print2,
print print3,
print print4
```

which means i haven't yet appended or made a new data set, as i am a python beginner I do not know how. 
My output of data displays as:

```
Nameone 
Nametwoo
5454
62158
Nameoneooo
Nametwoooo
1212
21
Nameoneww 
Nametwoww
3455
21332
```

I'm trying to take the keep the 1st and 2nd lines together, not nessasary, but then compare the 3rd and 4th lines, the 4th line must be bigger in order to be true for me, so i only want to output the lines where that would be true. thus in the above sample code, only the middle 4 lines would end up outputting

```
[Nameone: Nametwo, 5454-62158], etc.
```

Comment: You only show output. Which `for` loop are you talking about?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to post the code.

Comment: yes i want to take my outputted data and move into a set or list so i can do stuff to it.

Comment: You can format the output with print("[ %s: %s, %d-%d]" % n1, n2, i1, i2)

Comment: @jim i want to further use the data and do stuff to it, so create a set or list with it

Comment: l1.append(n1+ ": "+n2)   l1.append(str(i1)+"-"+str(i2))  bigl.append(l1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example would be, instead of doing

```
for _ in range(_):
    print name1
    print name2
    print value1
    print value2
```

you could do,

```
values = []
for _ in range(_):
    values.append([name1, name2, value1, value2])
```

For your specified format (and if I understand it correctly), I would do

```
values = []
for _ in range(_):
    if value2 > value1:
        values.append([name1, name2, value2 - value1])
```

Comment: A more concise way would be to use a list comprehension, especially in this instance.

Comment: He mentions using nested `for` loops, and being a beginner, so I tried to keep it as simple as possible.